# Why are the eigenvalues of $X'X$ equal to that of $XX'$ when $X$ is a design matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

The title says it all. If $X$ is a design matrix (columns containing variables, rows containing observations), I have observed that eigs($X'X$)=eigs($XX'$). I actually found this by accident when I was trying to compute eigenvalues of a covariance matrix in Matlab. Why is this the case? Can someone provide me some intuition, proofs, and/or reading materials?

Comment: If your design matrix has $n$ rows & $p$ columns (& let's say $p<n$ WLG), you mean that the first $p$ eigenvalues are the same, right?  Otherwise $eig(XX')$ has more eigenvalues than $eig(X'X)$.

Comment: Technically, yes. However, I believe the ranks will be the same. I guess I should clarify by asking why all non-zero eigenvalues are the same.